# SQL join and get another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join two tables so I can easily order it, as one contains the names of items and the other doesn't. The tables:

user_games: UGID, UID, APPID, playtime

games_steam: APPID, name

my SQL so far:

```
SELECT user_games.*
FROM user_games
JOIN games_steam ON user_games.APPID = games_steam.APPID
WHERE user_games.UID = '76561197996836099'
GROUP BY user_games.APPID
ORDER BY games_steam.name ASC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Just no idea how to get the name column into this aswell.

Comment: `select user_games.*, games_steam.name`.

Comment: Well that was too simple, thanks.

Comment: Also, avoid ".*" and return only the necessary fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
  SELECT user_games.*, games_steam.name
  FROM user_games
  JOIN games_steam 
  ON user_games.APPID = games_steam.APPID
  WHERE user_games.UID = '76561197996836099'
  GROUP BY user_games.APPID
  ORDER BY games_steam.name ASC
  LIMIT 0, 30
```